# Android fragment activity layout not finding view in multi-pane layout with findViewById

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragmentactivity

`findViewById(R.id.team_detail_container)` is failing to find the view. Is my problem with the xml or in the way I am constructing the FragmentActivity? How do I solve this?

To support a customised list for a fragment in the constructor of my fragment activity I have replaced

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_list);`

with

```
frag=(TeamListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        if (frag==null) {
            frag=new TeamListFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
```

So that my class now looks like this

```
public class TeamListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        TeamListFragment.Callbacks {

    private boolean mTwoPane;
    private TeamListFragment frag=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        frag=(TeamListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        if (frag==null) {
            frag=new TeamListFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
        }
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        if (findViewById(R.id.team_detail_container) != null) {

            Log.i("@@@@", "Team Detail Container has been found! Yaay!");
            mTwoPane = true;
            ((TeamListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.team_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }   
    }
```

The `if (findViewById(R.id.team_detail_container) != null) {` condition is never met despite the fact that team_detail_container exists in the xml file that is used

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/team_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        tools:context=".TeamListActivity" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/team_list"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

            <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:text="No data"/>
         </LinearLayout>        
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        /> 

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/team_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I know that this particular layout xml is being used as changes I make to the xml file are reflected in the app.
I also know that the condition is never met as I never get the log message `Log.i("@@@@", "Team Detail Container has been found! Yaay!");` and the behaviour  get is that when an item is selected the list view is replaced with the detail fragments instead of the detail fragments being displayed next to the list view because the item selected conditions are not being met

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
                // mTwoPane is never set! Why?

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(TeamDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        TeamDetailFragment fragment = new TeamDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.team_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, TeamDetailSwipeActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(TeamDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment doesn't get added to your layout tree immediately after committing the transaction. You'll have to wait till `onViewCreated` on the fragment was called. You could probably access the view within the `onStart`-Method of your Activity, but it would probably be a better idea to keep that logic within the fragment itself. The Activity shouldn't be concerned with what views are contained in a fragment.

Comment: That did the trick! I moved the condition to onStart and changed setActivateOnItemClick(true) to use the private member field mFrag and problem solved! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you're looking for the Fragment from the Activity, but since you're not using `setContentView`, the Activity doesn't actually have a View to look through.  Try getting the view from the Fragment instead using the `getView()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it gave me a huge clue as to what I needed to do. I have accepted @TimoOhr answer as it gave me the actual event I needed. Shame I can;t accept both answers